# How do I debug a crash on a worker thread in iOS?

Tags: ios

This typically happens when returning from the background. I have a hard time reproducing the issue. My initial guess is that it is a race condition with a network connection, but I may be wrong. Are there any other clues I am missing here?

```
Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.networking.connection.0x5a6540
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38f422a8 __close_nocancel + 12
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f5083e _dispatch_source_cancel_callout + 98
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f4d122 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 230
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f4ae8e _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 78
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f4adbc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 36
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f4b91a _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 182
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f4babc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34758a4e _pthread_wqthread + 358
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x347588e0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Did you figure out what is going on? It is happening again on iOS 8 and have hard time finding the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling some connection that are vausing the crash, i think that you should put a breakpoint in the code that calls this connection